# How to make a class in pytorch use GPU

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch, tensor

So I am running some code and getting the following error in Pytorch: "RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same"

From what I understand, this means that my model may not be pushed to the GPU, while the input data already is using the GPU. I can share my code if that would help (I am refraining from doing it right now since it is longer than a small code snippet).

I am aware that I can do something like

```
    myModel=Model()
    myModel.cuda()
```

However, I am making a class as part of a custom module that will be added to a Sequential wrapper. So, I can't really make an object out of it (I'm not good with OOP terminology, so I apologize for any technical writing mistakes). I was wondering if there is a way to get around this issue, and make the class always use the GPU, even though I never explicitly define an object?

If this was not clear enough, I can post my code, but as previously warned it may take some time to go through (not too long, but not very convenient either).

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Here is the code, I presume the issue is in the RLSTM class, since there was not an error before I added this.

```
class VGG(nn.Module):
'''
VGG model 
'''
def __init__(self, features): # features represents the layers array
    super(VGG, self).__init__()
    self.features = features
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(),
        nn.Linear(512,512),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.Dropout(),
        nn.Linear(512, 512),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.Linear(512, 10),
    )
     # Initialize weights
    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
            n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
            m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
            m.bias.data.zero_()


def forward(self, x): # x is the image, we run x through the layers
    print(x.size())
    x = self.features(x) # runs through all features, where each feature is a function
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) 
    # after running through features, does sequential steps to finally classify
    x = self.classifier(x)
    # print(x)
    return x


def make_layers(cfg, batch_norm=False):
   # print("Making layers!")
    layers = []
    in_channels = 3
    for v in cfg:
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v
            layers+=[RLSTM()]

    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

class RLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(RLSTM,self).__init__()



def forward(self, image):
    print("going in rowlstm")
    global current
    global _layer
    global isgates
    size = image.size()
    b = size[0]
    indvs = list(image.split(1,0)) # split up the batch into individual images
    #print(indvs[0].size())
    tensor_array = []
    for i in range(b):
        current = 0
        _layer = []
        isgates = []
        tensor_array.append(self.RowLSTM(indvs[i]))

    seq=tuple(tensor_array)
    trans = torch.cat(seq,0)
    return trans.cuda() # trying to make floattensor error go away 
def RowLSTM(self, image): 
    global current
    global _layer
    global isgates


    # input-to-state (K_is * x_i) : 3x1 convolution. generate 4h x n x n tensor. 4hxnxn tensor contains all i -> s info

# the input to state convolution should only be computed one time 
    if current==0:
        n = image.size()[2]
        ch=image.size()[1]
        input_to_state = torch.nn.Conv2d(ch,4*ch,kernel_size=(1,3),padding=(0,1))
        isgates = self.splitIS(input_to_state(image)) # convolve, then split into gates (4 per row)
        cell=RowLSTMCell(0,torch.randn(ch,n,1),torch.randn(ch,n,1),torch.randn(ch,n,1),torch.randn(ch,n,1),torch.randn(ch,n,1),torch.randn(ch,n,1))
        # now have dummy, learnable variables for first row
        _layer.append(cell)

    else:   
        Cell_prev = _layer[current-1] # access previous row
        hidPrev = Cell_prev.getHiddenState() 
        ch = image.size()[1] 
    #   print("about to apply conv1d")
        state_to_state = torch.nn.Conv2d(ch,4*ch,kernel_size=(1,3),padding=(0,1)) # error is here: hidPrev is an array - not a valid number of input channel
    #   print("applied conv1d") 
        prevHid=Cell_prev.getHiddenState()
        ssgates = self.splitSS(state_to_state(prevHid.unsqueeze(0))) #need to unsqueeze (Ex: currently 16x5, need to make 1x16x5)
        gates = self.addGates(isgates,ssgates,current)
        # split gates
        ig, og, fg, gg = gates[0], gates[1], gates[2], gates[3] # into four, ADD SIGMOID!
        cell = RowLSTMCell(Cell_prev,ig,og,fg,gg,0,0)
        cell.compute()
        _layer.append(cell)
    # attempting to eliminate requirement of getting size

    #print(current)
    try:

        current+=1
        y=(isgates[0][0][1][current])
        return self.RowLSTM(image) 
    except Exception as error:
        concats=[]
        for cell in _layer:
            tensor=torch.unsqueeze(cell.h,0)

            concats.append(tensor)
        seq=tuple(concats)
        tensor=torch.cat(seq,3)
        return tensor

def splitIS(tensor): #always going to be splitting into 4 pieces, so no need to add extra parameters
    inputStateGates={}
    size=tensor.size() # 1 x 4h x n x n
    out_ft=size[1] # get 4h for the nxnx4h tensor
    num=size[2] # get n for the nxn image
    hh=out_ft/4 # we want to split the tensor into 4, for the gates
    tensor = torch.squeeze(tensor) # 4h x n x n

    # First, split by row: Creates n tensors of 4h x n x 1
    rows = list(tensor.split(1,2))

    for i in range(num):
        # Each row is a tensor of 4h x n x 1, split it into 4 of h x n x 1
        row=rows[i]
        inputStateGates[i]=list(row.split(hh,0))

    return inputStateGates 


def splitSS(tensor): # 1 x 4h x n x 1, create 4 of 1 x h x n x 1 
    size=tensor.size() 
    out_ft=size[1] # get 4h for the 1x4hxn tensor
    num=size[2] # get n for the 1xhxn row
    hh=out_ft/4 # we want to split the tensor into 4, for the gates
    tensor = tensor.squeeze(0) # 4h x n x 1
    splitted=list(tensor.split(hh,0))
    return splitted 


def addGates(i2s,s2s,key):
    """ these dictionaries are of form {key : [[i], [o], [f], [g]]}
        we want to add pairwise elemeents """

    # i2s is of form key: [[i], [o], [f], [g]] where each gate is hxn
    # s2s is of form [[h,n],[h,n],[h,n], [h,n]]
    gateSum = []
    for i in range(4): # always of length 4, representing the gates
        gateSum.append(torch.sigmoid(i2s[key][i] + s2s[i]))

    return gateSum
```

Comment: Some code would help, you can skip the irrelevant parts to make it shorter. As long as your whatever class inherits `Module`, you can call `.cuda()` and it will be applied on all its children.

Comment: Ok, I will add some to my question now.

Comment: Are you creating the `torch.nn.Conv2d` object when you call forward? That can hardly be correct. If you look at VGG, it creates all those "Linear" things inside `__init__`. I think you need to learn how to [define a model](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_module.html)

Comment: Which torch.nn.Conv2d's are you referring to?

Comment: In forward of `RLSTM`, you called `RowLSTM`, which in turns creates `torch.nn.Conv2d`

Comment: I'll move those definitions inside __init__. What would go wrong if I left them there, just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the child modules *inside* the `__init__` function so that they can be registered as parameters of the module. If they are not parameters, `.cuda()` would not be call on them when you call `.cuda()` for the parent.

If you really needed dynamic parameters/modules declaration, take a look [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dynamic-parameter-declaration-in-forward-function/427/3). The key is [apaszke's answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dynamic-parameter-declaration-in-forward-function/427/4).

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is take the RowLSTM class, and add this between some VGG layers. Do you think it would be better if I just turned the RowLSTM part into a function, and added this function to the VGG class, instead of trying to combine the two? The problem with me putting convolutions in the __init__ is that then I won't have information on the number of channels I need. This would also make it difficult to add to to the layers array.

Comment: I was able to add the convolutions to __init__. I'll see if the error goes away

Comment: Error still persists  :(

Comment: I will mark as accepted but just to add: I had to do what hkchengrex said, but also I was adding a floattensor (cpu) to a cuda floattensor (gpu) which was the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

When you use GPU you need to change the dataset to a Cuda floating type tensor.
After putting simple if condition, I've never seen the same error so far.
I hope my sample code will be helpful to you.

```py
# Firstly, you need to network model to cuda.
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
net = VGG()
net.to(device) # or net.cuda()

# Secondly, you also need to change your dataset to Cuda Float Tensor.
if "GPU" in device:
    images = images.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
else:
    images = images.type(torch.FloatTensor)
```